# Ax=0, why A must be singular matrix for having x different from 0?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

For the given equation $Ax=0$ where $A$ is a square matrix and $x$ is a column vector, why $A$ must be a singular matrix (determinant $0$) in order to have $x$ different from null column vector?.

Comment: Think of regular multiplication, for example, the equation $xy=0$. For $y\not=0$, the only solution is $x=0$. Similarly, for a non-singular matrix, the only vector that will satisfy $Ax=0$ will be the null column vector.

Comment: While I'm not directly answering your question I think looking at the YouTube series "Essence of Linear Algebra" is a must if you are studying linear algebra and wish to deepen your understanding , it's a series of 10 minute videos .

Comment: Invertible matrices represent bijective linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$. In particular, such maps are _injective_ and hence have trivial kernels.

Comment: @Nuwanda  If you are ok, you can set as solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's simply a matter of linear dependence of the columns of A.

Indeed note that the multiplication $Ax$ correspond to a **combination of the columns** vectors of A by the coefficient of the vector $x$.

Thus:

1. if the columns of **A are linearly independent** (i.e. A not singular) the
   only way to have Ax=0 is that $x=0$
2. if the columns of **A are linearly dependent** (i.e. A singular) you
   may have $Ax=0$ also for $x\neq0$

Answer (score 3):

Because if $A$ is non-singular then its inverse $A^{-1}$ exists, and you have

$$0=A^{-1}0=A^{-1}\left(Ax\right)=\left(A^{-1}A\right)x=Ix=x$$